# Looking for a sci-fi book that involves Mankind's very last Starship

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, spaceship

The ship was crewed by an AI and carried the "hero" thru time to battle Orbs of energy that turned out to be what Man had evolved into.

I believe the book was written before Star Wars came out and was in English.I want to say I read it sometime late 60's 70's era.

Much of the book revolved around that amazing ship and its capabilities in the way it fought off its many attackers.  It had to travel in both time and space to get to where the main and final battle took place on Earth in its twilight days of existence  and afterwards gets them back home in the past again somehow.

Sorry it's all sort of vague but it's been a long time since I've read it and I always wanted to read it again.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. It would help if you could add more details about the book; When did you read this? In what language? Any more details you can remember about the plot?

Comment: Info added Mat.

Comment: That's great! Hopefully you'll get your book identified in no time. (You mean *Starship* instead of *Starhip* right?)

Comment: Starship wouldn't tag for me so I used Spaceship.